# JAX-WS webservice that uses Custom POJO as parameter and return value from a separate project

Tags: jax-ws

I am attempting to implement a Web Service that uses a POJO as a return value and a parameter as well.
Whenver I do that though, I get the following Exception...

```
Exception while deploying the app [EnterpriseLoggingPoCEAR] : Invalid ejb jar [EnterpriseLoggingPoC.jar]: it contains zero ejb.
```

Is there something I should be annotating my POJO with?  The POJO was included in the Build path...  I know in .net you have to annotate your class with `[DataContract]`... Do I have to do the same for JAX-WS pojo's?

One thing that I neglected to mention was that the POJO was in a package and a project that was not part of the Web Service project.  Once I moved the package into my project the error cleared up and I was able to deploy the project locally.  Now I thought I added my project to the build path of the other web service project.  But it would still throw that exception.  Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you are deploying an EJB module. You need an interface with `@Local` or `@Remote` annotations in that module.

Comment: Seems like having that POJO as a seperate JAVA project is what was causing the problem.  I just pulled the Package into the same project, but that seems strange.  I will have to consider this further.

Comment: Maybe you need to fix the project references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eclipse can help with references between projects for to reuse classes and libraries. For example, if you have an EAR project that contains a Web module and a EJB module, you can share between them domain classes (e.g. with `@Entity` annotation) or interfaces (with `@Remote` o `@Local` annotation).

If you check the project properties of EnterpriseLoggingPoCEAR, you could see something similar to:

[image]

In the images, the project ExampleModel is a *typical* Java project. This project has a additional facet: **Utility Module**. This facet is add automatically when you using the **Add...** button in the EAR properties.

[image]

The error that you mention is because you add a EJB module *without* any *EJB*.

[image]

Also instead of reference to another project, you can add a jar in the lib folder of EAR.

[image]

By the way, if you reference the project, this is also done automatically.

Comment: Adding the utility module facet to the pojo and making sure I reference the project seems to have fixed the problems.  Thanks.